# Meta QA progam: posting the same question on several QA websites

Tags: windows, linux

I am looking for a program for Microsoft Windows, Linux or web service that can allow the user to post the same question at once on several QA websites such as Stack Exchange, Quora, Reddit, or Yahoo! answers. Ideally, it should make it convenient to see replies/answers/comments to the questions, and allow the user to replies back as well as vote.

Any price and license is fine.

Comment: Any answers or comments are welcome.

Comment: I am still interested in this question.